# How can I restrict API info to user? Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, api

I already have authentication with `api_token` working correctly, but I want my consumer to make an API request and return the info respecting only to his `user_id`.
I know I can do this by passing info in the URL, as I have it right now in `Route::get('/getOrder/{user_id}','OrderController@indexByUser');` but I'm afraid that any user could just enter another `user_id` and get the orders from another User.

api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {

    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

  Route::get('/getOrder/{user_id}','OrderController@indexByUser');
});
```

Login and Logout gives/clears `api_token` respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization is a way to authorise a user to perform specific actions on specific resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create own midlleware, were set this logic.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->getId() !== $request->getPathInfo()) { // if userId contains in path
            return redirect(back(413));
        }
       
        return parent::handle($request, $next, $guards);
    }
```

(this is only example code )

Or you can use policies
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-policies